# Python Boto3 ARN as Input String being Ignored

Tags: python, boto3

I'm trying to pass in an ARN as a string to `client_wafv2.list_resources_for_web_acl` to show all resources attached to a WebACL, but doesn't seem to accept the string. I've confirmed the type string is within the for loop and the ARN is listed.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/wafv2.html#WAFV2.Client.list_resources_for_web_acl

```
##Get RegionalWebACLs
client_wafv2 = boto3.client('wafv2', region_name=region)
list_web_acl_regional = client_wafv2.list_web_acls(
Scope='REGIONAL',
 )
webAclArnList=[]
for webAcl in list_web_acl_regional['WebACLs']:
 webAclArnList.append(webAcl['ARN'])

for WebAclResource in webAclArnList:
    print(WebAclResource)
    print(type)WebAclResource))
    list_resources_for_web_acl = client_wafv2.list_resources_for_web_acl(
    WebACLArn=WebAclResource
            )

print(json.dumps(list_resources_for_web_acl, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

RESULT IS EMPTY

```
<class 'str'>
arn:aws:wafv2:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:regional/webacl/webacl-name/068a9bcb-eac7-4ec0-8aa5-xxx
<class 'str'>
arn:aws:wafv2:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:regional/webacl/webacl2-name/8582b19d-4f20-480d-b31e-xxx
{
    "ResourceArns": [],
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "content-length": "19",
            "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
            "date": "Sat, 05 Feb 2022 22:54:40 GMT",
            "x-amzn-requestid": "3e6f7de2-68b9-4f28-8cb1-xxx"
        },
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "RequestId": "3e6f7de2-68b9-4f28-8cb1-xxx",
        "RetryAttempts": 0
      }
    }
```

If I put the ARN in manually it works and the resources attached to the WebACL are shown:

```
client_wafv2 = boto3.client('wafv2', region_name=region)
list_resources_for_web_acl = client_wafv2.list_resources_for_web_acl(
     WebACLArn="arn:aws:wafv2:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:regional/webacl/webacl-name/068a9bcb-eac7-4ec0-8aa5-xxx")
    print(json.dumps(list_resources_for_web_acl, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

RESULT CONTAINS LB:

```
{
    "ResourceArns": [
        "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXX:loadbalancer/app/alb-waf-test/cb762e83xxxx"
    ],
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "content-length": "131",
            "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
            "date": "Sat, 05 Feb 2022 23:00:10 GMT",
            "x-amzn-requestid": "00ed1250-40d4-44dc-aff5-0de2790xxxx"
        },
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "RequestId": "00ed1250-40d4-44dc-aff5-0de2790xxxx",
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The json dumps needs to be within the loop, currently you only dump the result from the very last iteration.

Comment: Thank you! I was tired last night. Happy to mark resolved if you want to create an answer